# Responsive fit to box SVG using VH expressed height

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I would like to be able to fit my SVG graph to my div in the way aspectratio is ignored (fit to screen). However, when I change the window width, my chart goes out of my yellow box. How can I correct this keeping using a vh-expressed div height ?

[image: not fitted graph to the yellow box]

```css
.svg-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  /* aspect ratio */
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.svg-content-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-swipe-left="showMenu.value = true" data-ng-swipe-disable-mouse="">
  <div aw-resolve-loader="" ui-view="main" class="view reveal-animation ng-scope">
    <div style="float: left" class="ng-scope"></div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <div class="svg-container">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 800 600" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path class="line" d="M0,600L114.28571428571428,300L228.57142857142856,562.5L457.1428571428571,225L571.4285714285714,375L800,0"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ea7AK6kkvAVf8KIsnZwQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you are assigning a `height` in viewport units only to the container but not the actual SVG element. Because of this, the `height` of your container always remains responsive (as `60vh`) but `height` of the `svg` element changes depending on the `width` and the `viewBox` settings. This makes part of your SVG get clipped due to `overflow: hidden` on the container element.

You can verify the above by removing `overflow: hidden` from the container and adding a `border` to the SVG element.

To fix this issue, just add the below CSS properties to your `svg` element. This would make sure that the SVG is always only as big as the container.

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.svg-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;  /* aspect ratio */
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.svg-content-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-swipe-left="showMenu.value = true" data-ng-swipe-disable-mouse="">
  <!-- uiView: main -->
  <div aw-resolve-loader="" ui-view="main" class="view reveal-animation ng-scope">
    <div style="float: left" class="ng-scope"></div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <div class="svg-container">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 800 600" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path class="line" d="M0,600L114.28571428571428,300L228.57142857142856,562.5L457.1428571428571,225L571.4285714285714,375L800,0"></path>
          <!--rect x="50" y="200" width="250" height="40" /-->
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another possible option would be to set the parent container to `display: block` and then set the required dimensions directly to the `svg` element.

```css
.svg-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
svg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh; /* aspect ratio */  
}
```

```css
.svg-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.svg-content-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;  /* aspect ratio */
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-swipe-left="showMenu.value = true" data-ng-swipe-disable-mouse="">
  <!-- uiView: main -->
  <div aw-resolve-loader="" ui-view="main" class="view reveal-animation ng-scope">
    <div style="float: left" class="ng-scope"></div>
    <div class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
      <div class="svg-container">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 800 600" preserveAspectRatio="none">
          <path class="line" d="M0,600L114.28571428571428,300L228.57142857142856,562.5L457.1428571428571,225L571.4285714285714,375L800,0"></path>
          <!--rect x="50" y="200" width="250" height="40" /-->
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```